# Поиск данных в массиве js

Tags: javascript, массивы

Всем привет,имеется вот такой массив данных

```
var obj = [{
    name: 'Test',
    expirence: '364 days',
    Frontender: true,
    Backender: true,
    company: 'aaa'
  },
  {
    name: 'Test 2',
    expirence: '367 days',
    Frontender: true,
    Backender: false,
    company: 'aaa'
  },
  {
    name: 'Test 3',
    expirence: '731 days',
    Frontender: true,
    Backender: false,
    company: 'Cccc'
  },
 {
    name: 'Test 4',
    expirence: '731 days',
    Frontender: true,
    Backender: false,
    company: ''
  }
];
```

Как найти:

1) есть ли в массиве хотя бы один Fullstack (фронтендер и бекендер одновременно)

2) являются ли все разработчики фронтедерами

3) всех работающих в компании например "aaa"

4) все ли работают в компании (у всех ли поле 'company' заполнено)

Буду очень благодарен

Comment: да, да, Test и Test 2, нет

Answer (score 3):

У массива в js есть масса полезных методов. Нас интересует пара:

- `filter(callback)` - возвращает новый массив с элементами, для которых callback(element) вернул truthy значение (нечто, что приводится к true, непустая строка, ненулевое число и т.п.)
- `every(callback)` - возвращает true если callback(element) возвращает truthy значение **для каждого** элемента в массиве
- `some(callback)` - возвращает true если callback(element) возвращает truthy значение **хотя бы для одного** элемента в массиве

```js
// Исходные данные
var data = [{name: 'Test', expirence: '364 days', Frontender: true, Backender: true, company: 'aaa'}, {name: 'Test 2', expirence: '367 days', Frontender: true, Backender: false, company: 'aaa'}, {name: 'Test 3', expirence: '731 days', Frontender: true, Backender: false, company: 'Cccc'}, {name: 'Test 4', expirence: '731 days', Frontender: true, Backender: false, company: ''} ];

// 1. Есть ли fullstack?
// Применим фильтр
let hasFullstack = data.some(e => e.Frontender && e.Backender);
// 2. Все ли front?
let areAllFront = data.every(e => e.Frontender);
// 3. Выборка по компании
let aaaEmployers = data.filter(e => e.company === 'aaa');
// 4. У всех заполнена company
let areAllCompanyFilled = data.every(e => e.company);
console.log(
  hasFullstack, 
  areAllFront, 
  aaaEmployers.map(e => e.name), 
  areAllCompanyFilled)
```

Answer (score -1):

Вероятно вам поможет функция поиска в массиве, вот.

```
function search(array) {

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      for(key in array[i]) {
          if(array[i].Backender == "true" and array[i].Frontender == "true") {
              return "FullStack";
          }
      }
  }

  return -1;
}
```

По подобному алгоритму, можно решить все ваши задачи, просто добавьте проверку например на есть ли у компании «ааа» если есть, упускаем return, если нет возвращаемые false. По вашей просьбе могу уточнить ответ.

UPD:

```
function search(array, key, value) {

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if(array[i].key != value) {
          return false;
      }
  }

  return true,
}


search(тут указываем массив, тут указываем какое свойство надо проверять, тут какие у свойства должны быть значения);
```

Например

```
 search(array, "company", "aaa");
```

Если у всех работающих компания будет "aaa" вернёт `true` В противном случае `false`.

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста) я просто совсем новичок пока

Comment: Добавил детали.

Comment: А ты пробовал запускать код, который написал? Первый блок имеет синтаксическую ошибку, второй работает совсем не так как задумывалось